# Should there be an apostrophe if not why?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, apostrophe

In the short sentence below  should there be an apostrophe?

> My Sisters protector.

Comment: Hi john, welcome to EL&U.  I regret to inform you that I've had to flag your question as 'very low quality'.  Please consider amending your question to make it a suitable question, which you can see the definition of in the [tour].

Comment: Are you referring to *one* sister or *more than one*  sister? (I believe you are talking about the former, since you have capitalised the S in "Sister" which should not generally be capitalised if it follows a word, in this case, the word being "My".)

Comment: could i have the appropriate grammar for both? @user

Comment: @user477343 Please do not ask further questions, please flag, and, if you feel is appropriate, downvote.

Comment: @john in both cases, there is an apostrophe, but it is placed differently: one *before* the last "s" in "Sisters" and one *after* it ;)

Comment: @Lordology the user is new; give him a bit of time to get used to this and be a little more welcoming.

Comment: @user477343 I would strongly disagree.  There are severe issues he is blatantly ignoring, and in his reply to my comment, he is subtly putting me down which goes against the guidelines and rules.  Rudeness and ignorance aren't tolerated here.

Comment: it's the internet, someone who's here to "uphold the rules and guidelines" should be a little bit more helpful next time and thank you @user you've been very helpful

Comment: @Lordology I see... well, with that being said, apologies if my previous comment to you came across as rude. There might be severe issues that the user is unaware of,  however I am now just making assumptions here.

Comment: @john I apologise for any inconvenience, but, as it _is_ the internet, be nice and listen.  Thank you.

Comment: @user477343 It's fine, apologies if _my_ comments came across as rude, and have a nice day.  Issue resolved...  Although, john, I humbly ask that you amend your mistakes to make this site a better place.  Thanks.

Comment: Whether it needs an apostrophe depends on what you're trying to express. Please [edit] to explain what you're trying to express. For example, "auditors general" doesn't use an apostrophe if it's the plural of "auditor general", but it does if you're talking about the general (boss) of an auditor.

Comment: @Lordology *does* have a point. The main reason he/she has flagged the question is so you could edit it and make the site look better. Hey, perhaps give some background info so we could answer your question better! (I will use the term "they" to refer to the gender of Lordology, hereafter.) Being flagged isn't too big of a deal, but only allows moderators to examine your question in particular, I believe. So, if you edit your question to meet with the criteria of this site, which I believe is reasonable, then the moderators won't put your question on hold or close it or anything :)

Comment: @user477343 Thanks for the comment.  john, I strongly advise you to edit your post, as if the mods come and review the flags and see your slight ignorance and 'personal attack' as the site calls it, I wouldn't want a new user to get issued a [warning](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: @Lordology no problemo :D

Comment: Is *My Sisters* a proper name (as in the name of a restaurant) or is the capital *S* a typo, and you'd really meant to type *My sisters*?

Comment: There must be an apostrophe, *sister* must not be capitalized, and this is not a sentence but a fragment. All of these things are common knowledge, and I personally came to know all these things by closing the Internet and opening a book instead. I can only recommend you do likewise.

Answer (score 2):

> > In the short sentence "My Sisters protector." should there be an apostrophe?

The answer is **yes**.

However, there are two cases we must consider:

> - You have *one* sister; or
> - You have *more than one* sister.

In each of these cases, the apostrophe is positioned differently. Let's take a look at the first case (see what I did there? :P)

> **Case 1:** You have *one* sister.

If you have one sister, then the apostrophe is placed *before* the last "s" of "Sisters". This is to say, the sentence should be written out as follows:

> My **sister's** protector.

So the protector protects your one sister. (Note that I do not capitalise the first letter of the word "sister" unlike what you did, but your question is not about this in particular, though I do feel it is necessary to point this capitalisation out.)

Now, let's examine the second case:

> **Case 2:** You have *more than one* sister.

If you have more than one sister, then the apostrophe is placed *after* the last "s" of "Sisters". This is to say, the sentence should be written out as follows:

> My **sisters'** protector.

So the protector protects all your multiple sisters.

:)

Comment: But look at the capitalization. What if it's a *singular* proper name? Let's say it's the name of a restaurant. I like to eat at *My Sisters* downtown. It's still singular, but most style guides would still have you add only an apostrophe at the end because of how the final word is pronounced: *Pizza is on the My Sisters' menu.* Alternatively, it would be rephrased to avoid confusion: *Pizza is on the menu at My Sisters.*